# "broke into" or " broke in to"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

> How thieves **broke into** Hatton Garden vault. [BBC](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-london-32416045)

because the **Broke in** is a phrasal verb, Shouldn't we say:

> How thieves **broke in to** Hatton Garden vault.

**Update:**

An example on *broke in to*:

> Daniel Wallace, 33, and Kacey Adams, 34, **broke in to** their home in London Road, Halstead, in April 2016. [BBC](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-kent-39065743)

Comment: _break in_ is a phrasal verb, but, as others have mentioned in their answers, _break into_ is also a phrasal verb. Many phrasal verbs with _in_ also work with _into_ (e.g., _get in trouble_ vs _get into trouble_).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break into something

1. to begin suddenly to do something

Then he broke into a run and we just couldn't catch him. 
Onishi broke into sobs and covered his eyes with a handkerchief.

2. to enter a place by using force

His apartment has been broken into twice, even though he had good locks on the door.

[Break into idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/break+into)

Answer (score 2):

From Free Dictionary [break into](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/break+into) means:

> to enter a place by using force

sentence:

> His apartment has been broken into twice, even though he had good
>   locks on the door.

So the correct version is always "break into" in this sense and "into" here is a preposition.